# Is this geometric intuition for the relationship between curvatures correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, intuition, curvature

Given an element of $SO(n)$, [it can be decomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Group_properties) as the product of rotations through planes (two-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$), for example, using [Givens rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation).

However, because rotations don't commute, if we are only given a particular basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can not necessarily generate any element of $SO(n)$ as a product of rotations through planes spanned by pairs of any two basis vectors. (See the paragraph beginning with `"Notice that..."` [here](http://planetmath.org/dimensionofthespecialorthogonalgroup).)

Analogously, knowledge of *all* sectional curvatures (i.e. of every 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$) completely determines the Riemannian curvature tensor (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature) or [here](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/cis610/public_html/diffgeom5.pdf)).

But if we are only given the sectional curvatures corresponding to planes spanned by pairs of two vectors from a particular basis, then we do not know enough to determine the entire Riemannian curvature tensor (as the answers to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86434/calculating-the-riemann-curvature-tensor-out-of-sectional-curvature) argue).

**Question:** Are these two facts related or connected on some level?

In other words, can we intuitively understand the reason why we need *all* sectional curvatures to determine the Riemannian curvature tensor, and not just those correspond to the planes spanned by a particular given basis, to be that "rotations don't commute"?

Seemingly there would likely be a strong connection between $SO(n)$ and the Riemannian curvature tensor, since both are generated by the inner product/Riemannian metric.

An intuitive "argument" or a pointer to a reference would suffice for an answer.

Comment: I'm not an expert on geometry, but these don't seem related to me. The core issue is the degrees of freedom of the system, but I don't see a geometric connection between the fact that you have a non-zero number of degrees of freedom in the first example and the same in the second example.

Comment: @StellaBiderman This interpretation (in terms of degrees of freedom) makes sense to me. I think I might have read about the reasoning for the degrees of freedom for one or another at one point -- I'll have to try to find those sources and reread them to see if there is a similar reason why they have the same number of degrees of freedom, but it probably is more or less arbitrary.